# kubernetes ingress multiple tls certs under one host

Tags: certificate, nginx-ingress

is it possible to make nginx controller read certs from two different secrets, e.g,

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata: 
 annotations: kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx 
   enable-vts-status: "true" 
   prometheus.io/scrape: "true" 
   prometheus.io/port: "9913" 
   nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false" 
 labels: 
   app: myapp 
   name: myapp-nginx-ingress 
   namespace: myapp
spec: 
 tls: 
 - hosts: 
   - api.domain.com 
   secretName: 1st-ssl-secret 
   secretName: 2nd-ssl-secret
```

I've tried specified multiple secretName, but it seems that only the first one is taken.
The second one is ignored.